# Calculation of the greatest value

Tags: c#

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, because I can't seem to find where I'm messing up. Visual Studio highlights my if statements so I'm assuming that's where the problems is.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("First number: ");
            int num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Second number: ");
            int num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Third number: ");
            int num3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (num1 > num2 && num3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The greatest number is {0}", num1);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (num2 > num1 && num3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The greatest number is {0}", num2);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else if (num3 > num1 && num2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The greatest number is {0}", num3);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number are equal");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the if conditions, e.g. "if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3)" .

Comment: How about checking the error message Visual Studio or the compiler is giving? Then there will be no problem knowing where the error is, or what.

Comment: Do this if(num1>num2&&num1>num3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the && operator incorrectly. It is the binary logical AND operator, it returns true iff both it's arguments evaluate to true.

Instead of `(num1 > num2 && num3)` you have to write `(num1 > num2 && num1 > num3)` (and so on).

Answer (score 1):

```
               if (num1 > num2 && num3)
```

This does not compare first number to the other two.

You want

```
      if (num1 > num2 && num1> num3)
```

Also you should be using >= if there is a chance of having duplicates

In your code 2,2,1 would return "the numbers are equal"

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the entire thing with:

```
Math.Max(Math.Max(num1, num2), num3)
```

Or, if you are keen on using LINQ, you could put the three numbers in an array and then simply use the [Max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-5.0) function.

Answer (score 0):

> An if statement identifies which statement to run based on the value of a Boolean expression

in you code num2 and num3 are not boolean values so you need to actually create a boolean expression,

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)